# Connect to another system in a network

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application which reads data from a file on other systems.  I am able to connect to the other systems by changing the ipaddress in the web.config file.  I want a proper strategy where I can connect to the other systems in the network by entering the ipaddress/name of the other system in my application rather than changing the ipaddress in the web.config file everytime.

I am using:
vs2008
asp.net

I would appreciate if someone could help me out?

Comment: Supply more information about what you're looking for. Proper strategies might be; FTP, network share, email, pidgeon mail, running around with USB sticks, webservices, custom implementations, remoting client server setup, WCF, various p2p networks.

Comment: @Barfieldmv looking for a client server setup kind where i can connect to a client from the server by entering the ipaddress in my application rather than editing the web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [WCF web service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/11/getting-started-building-a-wcf-web-service.aspx) on the other system that opens the file and streams it back to your application.

Comment: Is there any other solution other than creating a webservice?

Comment: @Macnique I'm sure there's several solutions, but you asked for a proper strategy. I believe a web service is the proper way to go.

Comment: Because i am not good at WebServices ,i was wondering whether i can get another solution.

Comment: @Macnique I suppose another solution would be to place the files you need to read in a central location that all your applications/systems can read from.

Comment: I am able to read the file perfectly from various systems/machines in my network...my question here is everytime i want to connect to a different system  ,i have to change the ipaddress in web.config file...instead that i want to put an input textbox where a user can enter the ipaddress and hit a button it should connect to the respective system/machine.